# How to use a C dll within a c# program

Tags: c#, c, dll

I have a .c and a .h file modified to be used within a cpp application, in fact they have the

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
       extern "C"{
#endif
```

prepocessor lines. I was wondering if and how I can use the functions defined there within a c# program. Maybe I have to create a dll for that piece of code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch Dll using C# program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877157/launch-dll-using-c-sharp-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guys don't seem to get it - he doesn't have a dll, he has c++ source files:

You have two options

1. Translate the c++ code to C# and incorporate it directly into your application
2. Use a c++ compiler to create a dll from the source files and use PInvoke to access it

As far as if you need to modify the c++ code to create the dll or make it accessable from C#, we have no way of knowing without a posting of the full code.

Comment: My answer assumed he would try #2 which is not uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    public static extern int puts(string c);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Test");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

This **assumes** you are willing to compile your existing code into a .DLL

Comment: So I have to create a dll from the .c and .h files? Have I to modify the code before creating the dll?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clearly example on MSDN blog. You can use IntPtr to load DLL path.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx