# Running an exe converted to a dll from another exe

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

I have a completely functioning application that I have converted to a Dll.

I need to be able to run that application (now dll) out of an exe . Ive added the dll as a reference to the new exe and have tried to just instantiate a frmMain object from the namespace used in the dll and show it like I would in any other application.

However, I get a bunch of null reference exceptions in several of the references that I had in the exe that I converted to a dll.

I've also tried the solution here [Launch Dll using C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877157/launch-dll-using-c-sharp-program)
and tried jumping to the Program.cs Main() function at which point I get a "SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application." error.

Here is the dll's program.cs

```
namespace VTRS
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>

        [STAThread]
        static void  Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new frmMain());
        }

        //had to add this because exe can't find Main
        public void invokeMain()
        {
            Main();
        }

        //you have to have a constructor for the exe to instantiate this class
        public Program()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and here is the new applications code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Reflection.Assembly dll1 = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\VTRSTCACodeMaintenance.dll");
                if (dll1 != null)
                {
                    object obj = dll1.CreateInstance("VTRS.Program");
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("invokeMain");
                        mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work or point me in the right direction? I'm super confused and am not doing this by choice (I'm being told to by the boss)

Comment: Why are you using reflection to access the DLL?  Why not just access it natively?  I think all the problems you've mentioned stem from the fact that you're swimming up stream to use your DLL.  Just reference it and instantiate whatever classes you need from it.  You'll have to adjust the access modifiers of course.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure . Can you give me an example please ? I apologize but this is the first time I've really worked with dlls that actually display forms etc etc and me not just calling methods in the dll and getting the result.

Comment: Apologies, but I shouldn't have to give you an example.  Either you know how to do it or you don't, in which case I'd recommend getting a book or tutorial on C# and .NET and learning how to code.  Either way, it's off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need reflection, nor do you need to execute the `Main()` method of your original .exe file (indeed, you should probably just remove it, if that project is intended to just be a plain DLL).

You don't need reflection because, once you've added the assembly as a reference in your new project, all of the public types and members are accessibly in your new project. Just make sure you've declared `frmMain` as `public` (this is the default in Visual Studio, so it may already be `public`). Then instead of all that reflection rigmarole, all you need to do is what you'd normally do to show a form:

```
frmMain form = new frmMain();

form.Show();
```

or even just:

```
new frmMain().Show();
```

You don't need to execute the `Main()` method, because all it does is work that your new project already does:

- The `[STAThread]` sets the entry point thread (which becomes the main UI thread) to the STA apartment model. But since your new project is also (it seems) a Winforms program, you already have an entry point and a main UI thread that has been correctly configured. It's this thread in which the `Click` event for `button1` is raised, and so you are executing in that thread when the `button1_Click()` method is called.
- Likewise, the calls to set the visual styles and text rendering. You don't need to call these again, because your new project called them when it started.
- Finally, the call to `Application.Run(new frmMain())`. This call has three effects: it creates an instance of `frmMain()` (which you can do yourself as I noted above), it then passes that instance to the `Application.Run()` method so that method can call the `Show()` method on the form (again, you can do that yourself), and then the `Run()` method sits in a loop dispatching window messages. You also don't need to do that because, again, you are already in a Winforms program, which has already called `Application.Run()`, and is already dispatching window messages (which is how the `Click` event got raised in the first place).

So, stop trying to invoke the `Main()` method, just make sure the form class you want to use is `public` so it's visible from projects that reference the assembly, and just create and show the `frmMain` object the way you would if it were declared in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the access modifier of the class program just change it to public.
also if you don't load a changeable dll (dynamic) why you don't just reference it to the project as you would normally do with other dll's and call the main from the program class (you still need program class to be public)

Comment: Since I have the dll as a reference just do VTRS.Program.frmMain Form1 = new VTRS.Program.frmMain(); then do Form1.Show (); simple as that ? After changing the program class to be public of course .

Comment: For some reason I just expected it to be more complicated than that . I've called a million and one methods from dlls just assumed that it wouldn't be that easy to start up an application.

Comment: no frmMain isn't  a property of the class program but you can do this:
`VTRS.frmMain form1=new ...` and you can call any method in the program class like `VTRS.Program.invokeMain();`

Comment: Duhh. Mixup on classes there . My bad . I'll try it in just a bit .

Comment: A dll is just a bunch of classes and the **EXE** is also a bunch of classes the difference is **EXE** contain a structure so the **CLR** can start it automatically and that structure is simply a static method called `Main(string[] args)`

Comment: Awesome . I appreciate you.  If there's anything I can ever do for you . Just let me know !

Comment: Thank you, Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, in your project view right click on References --> Add New Reference --> Browse --> Find VTRSTCACodeMaintenance.dll(it should be in your \bin\debug folder) --> double click it --> click Ok.
That is basically.

Comment: I've got that in there . Thank you though